Is the leg of a right triangle inscribed in a quarter circle colinear with the terminus of a diameter of the full circle
I am having an issue with the following geometry Youtube problem. Fig. 1 presents the problem, where a right triangle is inscribed in a quarter circle. enter image description here
The radius AE is given (10 units) and it’s also given that C is the midpoint of EC. We are asked to find the area of the inscribed triangle. The numbers aren’t really important. My issue is a conceptual one. It’s easy to solve for AC applying the Pythagorean theorm to triangle AEC. The problem then is to solve for the lengths of AB and BC in order to get the area of triangle ABC. After solving for AC, the solution presented in the video involved completing the full circle containing the original quarter circle, extending AE to D, a diameter of the circle, and extending BC to D, a chord of the circle, as seen in Fig. 2. enter image description here
The poster of the video then applies Thale’s theorem and notes that ABD is a right triangle.  Then the rule that the products of the parts of intersecting chords are equal is applied: GC x CF = DC x CB. This allows us to solve for BC, since GC = 15, CF = 5, and DC = AC = 5 $\sqrt{5}$. Once CB is known we simply solve for AB and then calculate the area of ABC.
My question is, how do we know, or how can we prove, that points B, C and D are colinear? This raises the question of how many right triangles, with AC fixed as shown, can be inscribed in the original quarter circle? Clearly, if there is more than one, B, C and D will not always be colinear. As point B moves toward A, do we encounter another right triangle or will that only occur when AB is tangent at point A? In that case it seems there would only be one inscribed right triangle in the quarter circle.

By the inscribed angle theorem, a right angle inscribed anywhere on a circle subtends a semicircular arc, that is, the chord subtended by that angle is a diameter of the circle. So once we have a right angle at $B$ we know the two other intersections of the sides of that angle and the circle will be at opposite ends of a diameter or the circle.
We are given the names $A$ and $D$ for the two points at which the two sides of the right angle intersect the circle; therefore $AD$ is a diameter of the circle.
If you place $B$ at any other point on the circle you will get a right triangle
$\triangle ABD$ inscribed in the circle with a hypotenuse $AD$ that is a diameter of the circle.
Now look at the angle $\angle ADB$. The intersection of line $BD$ with the line $EF$ depends on  $\angle ADB$. So does the location of the point $B$. There is, in fact, a one-to-one correspondence between places where you can find $B$ on the quarter-circle arc $AF$ and places where $BD$ can intersect $EF$. If you know where $B$ is you know where the intersection point is, and vice versa.
So there is only one way to inscribe a right triangle $\triangle ABC$ in the quarter circle with $A$ and $C$ at the positions shown and a right angle $B$ on the arc.

Thank you for the helpful explanation. It seems that the original problem is contrived. We are presented with Figure 1. While it is possible, then, that B is in the correct location on the quarter circle to be colinear with C and D, we have no other information to indicate that it is. Yet the solution presumes that it is. Do you agree?

You are given the exact locations of $A$ and $C$. You are given that $\angle ABC$ is a right angle. There is only one place $B$ can be under those conditions, therefore that's where $B$ is. I don't know what's "contrived" about that. The problem is more easily solved when you construct the auxiliary point $D$ outside the original figure, but a lot of geometry problems are like that.

I wasn't clear about the constraints that the right angle at B placed on the BD leg of △ABD. I thought that if B were at some point B', closer to A, that △AB'C could be a right △ in which B'C would not be colinear with D. What I realize now is that in △AB'C, C would move have to move closer to E. In this new △, B'C'D will be colinear. I had thought point C was as significant as point B, but really the location of B is more important, and C just goes along for the ride. I guess that's what you meant when you said "If you know where B is you know where the intersection point is, and vice versa."

Yes, I think you have the correct idea now.

According to your diagram, I will give my answer below.
Let $∠ACE=\alpha$ and $∠ACB=\beta$.
By doing some angle chasing and congruent triangles you can find out ,$∠ACE=∠DCE=\alpha$.
Also $ABCE$ is cyclic quadrilateral as $∠AEC=∠ABC=\pi /2$.
So $∠AEB=∠ACB=\beta$.
Now in $\Delta AEB$,we can find out that $∠ACE=∠ABE=∠EAB=\alpha$.
Now using triangle sum theorem,we can find out that $2\alpha + \beta = \pi$.
Also,$∠BCD=2\alpha + \beta = \pi$.So B,C,D are collinear.
NOW,you can clearly see $\alpha$ is constant.So correspondingly $\beta$ is also constant.
Since $\beta$ is constant ,so $\Delta ABC$ is also constant.

I am having trouble seeing why ∠ACE=∠ABE, ∠ABE=∠EAB and ∠EAB=α. Also, what do you mean when you say that α and β are constant? Do you mean to say that those angles remain constant while point B moves along arc AF? It would seem that as B moves toward A, C would move towards E and α would decrease.

∠ACE=∠ABE since they are angles on same segment AB as ABCD is cyclic.Also in triangle  ABE we can see that tan α has a fixed value.So α has a fixed value.As we had found a relation between α and  β ,we can see β has also a fixed value.As hypotenuse and one angle of the triangle is known,so we can only have only 1 such triangle.
